# REACT Component not returning axios data

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint

I'm new to REACT and learning a ton.  I am trying to retrieve my data from a SharePoint list and render it to a page as a table but when I make my axios call, I get the following error. `tblData is undefined`
I know why I get the error and it's because the `this` in the axios is different from the outside, so I turned it into an arrow function and it still didn't work.  I then assigned the outer `this` to a variable and used it in the axios scope but that still didn't work.  Please help with!!

```
function Table(props) {

  return (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.title}</td>
        <td>{props.fname}</td>
        <td>{props.lname}</td>
        <td>{props.phone}</td>
        <td>{props.age}</td>
    </tr>
   )

 }

function App() {
  var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Axios List')/items";
  var tbl = this;
  axios.get(endPointUrl).then(response => {
    tbl.tblData = response.data.value.map(function (data) {
        return (
            <Table
                title={data.Title}
                fname={data.FirstName}
                lname={data.LastName}
                phone={data.Phone}
                age={data.age}
            />
        )
    })
 })
  return (
    { tblData }
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

When I console.log(response.data.value), I get
[image]

Comment: What you are getting in 'response '. Console the result to confirm please.

Comment: Functional components have are instanceless, there is no `this`. You need to use some component state, i.e. `const [tbl, setTbl] = useState({ tblData: []})`

Comment: I added the image I get when I console.log the response

Comment: @DrewReese, I don't understand what you mean.  Are you suggesting to use a class component

Comment: Image looking pretty messy. console it in such a way that show 'data' - title, firstName, Phone.

Comment: React works by rendering JSX and updates are done by updating a state object or passing new prop values to children components. When the axios call resolves it should update some state, and the state should be mapped in the return statement of the `App` component.

Comment: I was trying to follow the example I created here  https://codesandbox.io/s/render-styled-table-with-data-iou7k?file=/components/Table.js

Answer (score 1):

## Fundamentals

At first you should understand the fundamentals of React and thus that functional components are not just normal functions where you can mutate `this` scope and it will be magically available in the render methods.

React operates against virtual DOM and diffing is being done when it is needed (when state changes) but state !== this.

More about lifecycle of components is here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

## Why the codesandbox works

In your comments you linked https://codesandbox.io/s/render-styled-table-with-data-iou7k?file=/components/App.js which works, and it works because of simple reason, there is no another lifecycle of component. Data is static and not asynchronous and on first render it works with `this`.

However when you are fetching data from API you are making asynchronous code through promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

When you work with promises react component needs to be "informed" that it should re-rerender the DOM

## Solution - use component state (hooks)

```
function Table(props) {

  return (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.title}</td>
        <td>{props.fname}</td>
        <td>{props.lname}</td>
        <td>{props.phone}</td>
        <td>{props.age}</td>
    </tr>
   )

 }

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()

  var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Axios List')/items"

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(endPointUrl).then(response => setData(response.data))
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {data && data.value.map(_data => (
        <Table
                title={_data.Title}
                fname={_data.FirstName}
                lname={_data.LastName}
                phone={_data.Phone}
                age={_data.age}
            />
       )}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

### Explanation

Now your component will enter a several lifecycle states:

1. First render will be with data undefined and `return ( data && )` condition will evaluate to false which will render nothing.
2. Component will mount and by using `React.useEffect` we will trigger loading of data https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
3. We will set component state with `setData` which will trigger react reconciliation and re-rendering and `data` will be accessible.

Comment: Is ```const [data, setData] = React.useState()``` the same as ```const {data, setData} = React.useState()```?

Comment: I get an error on what you provided. 'endpointUrl' is undefined.

Comment: @OLA I edited the answer, there was only lowercase problem. And regarding the question, no, it's not I advice you to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment about destructuring, one which I used is for array, yours is for objects.